# custom validation on django-allauth

Tags: django-allauth

I'm using dj-allauth on my django app.  When people sign up to my django project/app, I want to check that the domain on their email matches mydomain.com.  Is this possible? I think I can do it by changing the [signup form](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#add-email-allauth-account-forms-addemailform).  I've tried the following which doesn't seem to do anything when I submit the signup form.  There aren't any errors.  It isn't checking for the domain, it's prompting for the user's nickname and then appending the domain automatically.

```
forms.py

class VSBSignupForm(SignupForm):

    def save(self, request):

        # Ensure you call the parent classes save.
        # .save() returns a User object.
        user = super(VSBSignupForm, self).save(request)
        user.email_address = user.username + "@mydomain.com"
        user.save()

        # You must return the original result.
        return user


settings.py

ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'myapp.forms.VSBSignupForm'}
```

I changed the template for the signup.html such that it asks for the nickname and password, but not the email address.

**edit** I tried putting a print statement in the form save method and it didn't print anything in the shell, which makes me think the form isn't being used.